# Trying to use a cc_library from a go_library and getting

Tags: c, go, bazel

Consider the following `BUILD` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")

cc_library(
    name = "c",
    srcs = [
        "c.c",
        "c.h",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "c.h",
    ],
)

go_library(
    name = "gl",
    srcs = [
        "g.go",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":c",
    ],
)
```

`bazel build :c` works, of course, but `bazel build :gl` errors out with:

```
ERROR: /.../BUILD.bazel:14:11: in deps attribute of go_library rule //cog:gl: '//cog:c' does not have mandatory providers: 'GoLibrary'. Since this rule was created by the macro 'go_library_macro', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation
```

I am using the latest version (v0.24.9) of go_rules.

I have read the documentation on Providers (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/skylark-provider.html), but AFAICT, they are only of interest to rules writers.

What is the approved way of linking a C/C++ library with go code?

Comment: If they're in the same directory, you could probably set `cgo=True` on your `go_library` portion and have the go library build the c files.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use a `cc_library` as a dependency is to use `cdeps`, not `deps`. Only after that will bazel complain about a missing `cgo`, too. So the correct incantation is:

```
go_library(
    name = "gl",
    srcs = [
        "g.go",
    ],
    cdeps = [
        ":c",
    ],
    cgo = True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [options of `go_library`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/core.rst#go-library), I think you want to add

```py
  cgo = True,
```

> If `True`, the package may contain cgo code, and srcs may contain C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++ files and non-Go assembly files. When `cgo` is enabled, these files will be compiled with the C/C++ toolchain and included in the package. Note that this attribute does not force cgo to be enabled. Cgo is enabled for non-cross-compiling builds when a C/C++ toolchain is configured.

*Disclaimer*: I'm not familiar with the `go_library`.

Comment: you are just quoting from the documentation, you are not answering the question. I can read, you know.

Comment: And yet, in your question, this field is missing.